# IE 8 does not load an image with a certain size

Tags: internet-explorer-8, image-size

Does anyone know if IE 8 does not load an image that is bigger than a certain size, like 600k?

The same image was loaded fine in IE 9, FF and Chrome.

If you are using an IE 8 browser, please try to hit this image.  It will not load, then try it with your FF or Chrome, it will work.  Strange

http://netjade.com/s1-sc5.1-1.jpg

Thanks

Comment: There shouldn't be an image size limit in IE8. Could you link us to the page having the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Open the image with photoshop, as you can see it has CMYK mode,
if you choose RGB mode and save it as JPG it'll works!